# Joomla Navigation CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla, content-management-system

Basically, I have to apply a backup of a Joomla Website, ... the problem is, that the navigation of the backup does not apply the correct CSS and therefore is not displayed correctly, which I found out by using inspect element.

Now I'm facing the issue that I have no idea on how to change the CSS-classes.

I compared the two template files and found no differences in how the CSS is applied:

```
<header id="header" class="single-menu flat-menu">
  <div class="navbar-collapse nav-main-collapse collapse">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="nav-main">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigation" style="none" />
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The navigation module implements the main menu, yet does not apply any extra CSS and neither does the main menu.

There are seemingly no differences in the template-file or the CSS-files.

So my question now is: How exactly does Joomla apply the correct CSS to the navigation? I can't seem to find any way and yet with inspect element you can see that the webpage where the navigation is displayed correctly has the class:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main">
  <li class="item-xxx dropdown">
```

and the one where it is displayed incorrectly has:

```
<ul class="nav menu">
  <li class="item-xxx deeper parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now:

My problem was that on the webpage the override for the default.php of the menu module was directly in the root/modules/mod_menu folder, which gets overridden on an update. 
So I had to copy the correct default.php into the new override folder (root/templates/template/html/mod_menu/ ) and everything worked again.